# Intent samples in Android developers not working

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to send an SMS using intent (my app is not compatible with the SMSManager Google conditions or requirements).

When I try to use the sample code from Google Android developers, it's not working.

Here is the web site : [Common Intents](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#java)

Here is the sample :

```
public void composeMmsMessage(String message, Uri attachment) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    intent.setType(HTTP.PLAIN_TEXT_TYPE);
    intent.putExtra("sms_body", message);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, attachment);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the intent is never started because the result of the test is always null.

So, I use a try catch around the startActivity(intent), but I would like to understand why the sample code is not working...

Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is to replace the `resolveActivity()` check with `try`/`catch`:

```java
public void composeMmsMessage(String message, Uri attachment) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    intent.setType(HTTP.PLAIN_TEXT_TYPE);
    intent.putExtra("sms_body", message);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, attachment);
    try {
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        // TODO something to tell the user that this didn't work
    }
}
```

If for some reason you want to stick with the existing approach, my guess is that you are testing on a newer Android phone or emulator. You will need to [add a `<queries>` element to your manifest](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/declaring) that matches your desired `Intent` structure.

Comment: Yes, thanks, this is the solution I've found. But my question is why the sample code from Google is not working ?

Comment: @Christian: "But my question is why the sample code from Google is not working ?" -- I covered that in my answer. You need to add a `<queries>` element to your manifest that matches your desired `Intent` structure.

Comment: Ah thank you and sorry, I understand now. So do I have just to add in the query : <intent> <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" /> </intent> ?

Comment: In my Manifest.xml, I already have this : <queries> <intent><action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SENDTO" /> </intent> </queries> and it's not working. May be I forgot something ?

Comment: @Christian: Probably you would also need to specify the MIME type, since your `Intent` includes a MIME type. Basically, it is the same rules for how `Intent` matches `<intent-filter>` for components. Extras do not count, but action strings, `Uri`, and MIME types do.

Comment: Unfortunatly, I already tested it, and I tried again to be sure, this is my query in Manifest :     <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SEND" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
And it's still always NULL...

Comment: @Christian: That is not the correct action string. First, you are using `ACTION_SENDTO`. Second, the action string does not have `ACTION_` in it. The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent?hl=en#ACTION_SENDTO) shows `android.intent.action.SENDTO`.

Comment: I also had tested with SENDTO, same...

Comment: I've found this article : https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/package-visibility-in-android-11-cc857f221cd9

Comment: Intent.ResolveActivity(PackageManager) return the Activity component that should be used to handle this intent. So I imagine that the problem is getPackageManager() that is not returning the package manager with which to resolve the Intent.